# Getting Value from XML and Store In Variable Using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
<Result>
  <resultDetails>
    <resultDetailsData>
      <itemProperties>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <type>LEVEL</type> 
        <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:int">5</value> 
      </itemProperties>
    </resultDetailsData>
  </resultDetails>
</Result>
```

I have the xml described above. I want to get the value of value tag (in this case, '5') using the value of the type tag, (i.e., LEVEL in this case) and store it in a variable using XSLT, so that i can use the variable later.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="myVar" select="Result/resultDetails/resultDetailsData/itemProperties/value"/>
<varoutput>
    <xsl:value-of select="$myVar"/>
</varoutput>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input XML you get this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<varoutput>5</varoutput>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the read variable to set an attribute (i.e. color of a row) you need to use **{**$variable**}** as below

```
<xsl:variable name="rColor" select="rowColor"/>
```

then

```
<fo:table-row background-color="{$rColor}">
```