# How to make a rest call and store xml response in a variable in XSLT?

Tags: xml, azure, xslt, xslt-1.0, azure-api-management

I am using XSLT 1.0. I am doing xsl transformation in azure apim policy.
I want to make a rest call using xslt and store the xml response in a variable. is it possible to do so?

Suppose Below get method api returns customer object in xml format :

http://customerinfo.com/customer/123

Output:

```
<Customer>
<id>123</id>
<name>John</name>
</Customer>
```

Call this api using xslt and save the response in a variable.

I tried doing below thing but it giving error.

```
<xsl:variable name="response">
<dp:url-open target="http://customerinfo.com/customer/123" response="xml" http-method="get" content-type="&apos;application/xml&apos;">
<xsl:copy-of select="$rest_request" />
</dp:url-open>
</xsl:variable>
```

Getting below error:

```
"Transform failed: 'url-open' is not a recognized extension element. An error occurred at (11,16).",
        "'url-open' is not a recognized extension element. An error occurred at (11,16)."
```

Comment: What do you get with `<xsl:variable name="response" select="document('http://customerinfo.com/customer/123')"/>`?

Comment: Getting below error:
xsl-transform (162.471 ms)
    {
    "messages": [
        null,
        "Transform failed: Execution of the 'document()' function was prohibited. Use the XsltSettings.EnableDocumentFunction property to enable it. An error occurred at (10,13).",
        "Execution of the 'document()' function was prohibited. Use the XsltSettings.EnableDocumentFunction property to enable it. An error occurred at (10,13)."
    ]
}

Comment: Do you know how to enable document function property in apim?

Comment: This thread may help--https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610547/getting-value-from-xml-and-store-in-variable-using-xslt